sci-fi story where an android is referred to as an intel, after the cpu manufacturer
This is probably young adult (thus the tag), but it is possible it is not.
The main detail I remember from the story is that androids existed; one character said of another, "she's an intel", after the cpu manufacturer.
I think a war was being fought, as I seem to remember one or more characters getting into fighter craft (jets?) shortly after that comment.
Given their term for androids, I'm guessing the book was written during or shortly after the huge "Intel Inside" marketing campaign of the 90's.

They are called Intel's (with the apostrophe), not intels, in the story?

@user14111 sorry for the confusion. I suspect I didn't finish the story. I only remember one, referred to in the singular: another character said "She's an intel".

Isn't it more logical that "intel" simply refers to them being intelligent (e.g. more intelligent than a preceding model)? Is there a reason to assume it's referencing the company?

@Joachim given how vividly I remember it, I suspect they spelled it out - but it is possible I jumped to conclusions.
